# Is Zscalar's HTTPS Everywhere for IE affiliated with EFF?

Tags: internet-explorer, https, https-everywhere

The [Electronic Frontier Foundation](https://www.eff.org/) has a tool called [HTTPS Everywhere](http://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) for Firefox, Chrome and Opera. But they don't list Internet Explorer.

There is a company called Zscalar that provides [HTTPS Everywhere for Internet Explorer](https://www.zscaler.com/httpseverywhere_ie.php).

I can't determine if the EFF approves of Zscalar's IE extension, or if the company hijacked the EFF tool's name. The only mention of Zscalar on the EFF website is the [HTTPS Everywhere Atlas](http://www.eff.org/https-everywhere/atlas/domains/zscaler.com.html). The closest I can find from Zscalar are link backs on the Zscalar website and a [Zscalar PDF](http://www.zscaler.com/research/plugins/ie/https-everywhere/https-everywhere.pdf) that points back to the EFF website.

The EFF tool is [free, open source and can be audited](http://www.eff.org/https-everywhere/development), but I don't see similar governance for Zscalar's tool. For example, I don't see mention of source code at [HTTPS Everywhere for Internet Explorer](http://www.zscaler.com/httpseverywhere_ie.php). And it looks like there's a "Free Trial" for [HTTPS Everywhere for Internet Explorer](http://www.zscaler.com/httpseverywhere_ie.php) (see the link on the right).

Is Zscalar's HTTPS Everywhere for IE affiliated with EFF?

Comment: No, it's not...